# Uniform method to convert data types

Tags: c#, .net, converters, typeconverter

.NET knows many ways to convert data types:

- `Convert`-class;
- Functions inside a type like `(Try)Parse` and `ToString`, etc.;
- Implementation of interface `IConvertable`;
- The `TypeConverter`;
- The implicit and explicit conversion operator;
- Am I missing another one?

So if am converting one datatype to another, I need to know both types and I need to know which conversion method to use. And this becomes pretty nasty if one of those two types (or both) is a generic type.

So my question is: I there is uniform (generic) way in .NET to convert one data type to another, which might use all the other limited methods?

Answer (score 2):

A good, generic way to convert between types is with [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytax8kf.aspx). Here's an example of how you could use it to write a generic converting method:

```
public static TResult Convert<TResult>(IConvertible source)
{
    return (TResult)System.Convert.ChangeType(source, typeof(TResult));
}
```

It, like other `Convert` methods, internally calls the [`IConvertible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) interface.

This will not make use of your other conversion options:

- The most common I'd think would be `ToString`; for that, you could add a check to see if `TResult` is `string` and if so, (after appropriate null checks) simply call `ToString` on your input.
- Using reflection you could check for:

  - the [`TypeConverterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ydke9w9.aspx) ([`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getconverter.aspx) seems to be the way to go from there)
  - `(Try)Parse` methods, (which you'd invoke), and
  - implicit/explicit conversion operators (the methods `op_Implicit` and `op_Explicit`, which you'd likewise invoke)

These are each fairly self-explanatory if you know a bit about reflection, but I could elaborate if any prove difficult.

Comment: Updated my answer to address the other conversion methods mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You imply those are all the same
They are not
Pick the appropriate

Convert Class

> Converts a base data type to another base data type.

Parse is from string

ToString is a to string

IConvertible Interface

> Defines methods that convert the value of the implementing reference
>   or value type to a common language runtime type that has an equivalent
>   value.

TypeConverter Class

> Provides a unified way of converting types of values to other types,
>   as well as for accessing standard values and subproperties.

Yes you need to know the type you are converting to.
And you should be aware if the type you are converting from.

With generics there is no built in.
At best you provide a method.
But why do you need to convert generics?

You seem to imply that more than one way is a bad thing.
For a single way then I like the answer from Tim S.  +1
But that does not mean I would ever use it.

The are even more ways to get data from a SQL database.
Is that a bad thing?

Comment: Where do I imply that?